# Texture2D can't find my sprite - how to setup the content directory in XNA

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

So I keep getting told that `spr_lives` can't be found.  I'm working out of a book and using the samples given to me (have not changed the code or folder structure, so it /should/ work) but nothing's working unfortunately.  I know it's a directory issue but I'm unclear on how to remedy it.

Picture of both code and folder structure:

[image]

Comment: What are the property settings for spr_lives? Right click in solution explorer and click properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to ensure that the images in your content project has this properties:

[image]

You have to check if your Xna game project have a reference to your content project:

[image]

You can check your /bin/debug/Content folder, to see if the xnb files are there:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping!  The images DO have the right properties.  Is this setup properly for the content reference? http://imgur.com/CdPxfES     The xnb files are NOT in my bin/debug/Content folder.

Comment: Content projects must be referenced by an unique game project... if you have two references, the xnb will be in the other project... if so, remove the content reference in FlyingSprites project

Comment: That was precisely what my issue was.  Thanks so much!  I'm not sure how to accept your answer as the correct one :/.